# Include SET options in a function

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a Function that creates a few temporary tables and `JOINS` to those temporary tables. When I `CREATE` the Function I can include this line at the top of the query:

```
SET check_function_bodies = false;
```

This prevents the error ***'relation does exist'*** from being raised. So far so good, but is it possible to include the same `SET` line when calling the function, or should it be included in the function definition itself?

Here is my actual function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reporting."rsp_TermPositionRawData_WIP"( /* parameters */ ) RETURNS void LANGUAGE 'sql'
COST 100 VOLATILE SET check_function_bodies=false
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredRequests;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredResponses;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ranks;    

    CREATE TEMP TABLE FilteredRequests AS
       SELECT /* large query */;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE FilteredResponses AS
       SELECT /* large query that references "filteredrequests" */
    CREATE TEMP TABLE Ranks AS
       SELECT /* large query that references "filteredresponses" */
$BODY$;
```

The error message is

```
ERROR: relation "filteredrequests" does not exist LINE 116: INNER JOIN FilteredRequests FRQ ON FRQ.QuoteID
```

Comment: Can you also add the function to your question?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error during `CREATE FUNCTION` you have to `SET` the parameter the way you did. There is no way to include that in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

The `SET` clause of `CREATE FUNCTION` controls the parameters when the function is executed, not when it is defined.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your answer. Did you mean SELECT FUNCTION in your first sentence?

Comment: Sorry for being too terse. My first sentence means that the way you are doing it now (first run a `SET` statement, then run the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement) is the proper way to do it. There is no way to do that in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a problem  cresting the function, but when I call it in a SELECT statement, specifying values for the arguments, I get the 'relation does not exist' error.

Comment: At the time when you execute the function, all referenced objects must be there, else you will of course get an error. I think that you should [edit] your question and show your function code as well as a quoted error message.

Comment: You don't get the error if you issue `SET check_function_bodies = false;` first, right? And the function runs fine, right?

Comment: Not quite. I don't get the error when I include the SET option in the CRATE statement, but when I try to run the function using a SELECT statement (including the SET option at the very start of the statement, I get the error. Maybe I should use actual tables rather than temp tables and simply truncate them at the start of the function.

Comment: Or you use PL/pgSQL and dynamic SQL. The problem seems to be that the same name references different objects.